# How to insert time into a DATE type?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I inserted a tuple using the TO_DATE function, but it turns out to be '05/01/2015' when I do the query. There is no time shown. Anything is wrong?

```
INSERT INTO course_section VALUES(1,'MWF',TO_DATE('10:00:00 A.M.','HH:MI:SS A.M.'));
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there. The `DATE` column is actually a date and time, accurate to the second. If you don't specify a date part, it defaults to the first day of the current month.

The default Oracle format for showing dates is `DD-MON-RR`, which is *day number / month short name / year with century rollover*.

To get the time, specify a custom format using the `TO_CHAR` function. To see your time using a 24-hour clock, do the following (where `x` is your date column):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(x, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM course_section;
```

To see your time using a 12-hour clock with AM/PM, do this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(x, 'HH:MI:SS AM') from course_selection;
```

Or you can use `PM` instead of `AM` in the format string; you'll get the same result either way:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(x, 'HH:MI:SS PM') FROM course_selection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to your specs for your program or session

For example in SQL*Plus, add to login.sql

alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

For SQL Developer, set in Preferences > Database > NLS

When coding your apps, using TO_CHAR is good if you want to force a specific date format.